# Why doesn't my form update the database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Sorry for the amateur question here, but I've created a form that, for the life of me, I cannot debug the reason as to why it won't submit the updates into the database.

An example is here: www.dominicharrison.co.uk/projects/Portfolio/admin

Code:

```
<?php
require_once('../_inc/glob.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages`");

echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Location</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";

while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $array['id'] . "</td><td>" . $array['name'] . "</td><td>" . $array['location'];
    echo "</td><td><a href=\"?editid={$array['id']}\">Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"?delete={$array['id']}\">Delete</a></td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

// Defines the edit and delete functions

$edit = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['editid']);
$delete = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['delete']);

// Edit function!

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '{$edit}'");
$array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);

if($edit != "") {
    ?>
    <p>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo $array2['name']; ?>" type="text"><br />
    <input name="location" value="<?php echo $array2['location']; ?>" type="text"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit!">
    </form></p>

    <?php
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);

        mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET id = '{$edit}', name = '{$name}', location = '{$location}' WHERE id = '{$edit}'");
     }

}
```

Comment: Check to see if your query is succeeding - if it's not, there'll be a helpful error message in `mysql_error()`. You should also look at using mysqli_ or PDO - they'll help you write code that's more secure.

Comment: It might be a strange question in return, where do you submit to exactly?

Comment: @dmaij - if you leave the action blank, a form will submit back to its own URL.

Comment: @andrewsi- tnx, I always try to stick with MVC instead of lean PHP as described here.

Answer (score 2):

Since your form posts to the same page, this is what happens...

```
$edit = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['editid']); // THIS IS NULL FOR POSTS

...

if($edit != "") {   // THIS WON'T BE TRUE FOR POSTS
```

and thus, it will never get to your POST process of your script.  Reorganize your script - your POST processing code should likely be at the top (IF you continue to go with this one-script business.... which you shouldn't).

Comment: Also see @Rob Adams answer; submit is never posted, because there is no input with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a $_POST['submit'];

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Add name to your submit button. This creates the post variable that you're missing.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit!">
```

And your table will update. However, you will need to refresh the page, as you're calling the select long before you call update.

Comment: Please point out the missing "name" attribute in the submit button. It's what causing the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your form isn't submitting the id, so your SQL can't match anything in the `WHERE id=` clause.

1). Add a hidden field to your form to submit the editID you're getting from the $_GET array:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $edit; ?>" />
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo $array2['name']; ?>" type="text"><br />
    <input name="location" value="<?php echo $array2['location']; ?>" type="text"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit!">
</form>
```

2). Capture the edit id in your submit logic:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
        $edit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

        mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET id = '{$edit}', name = '{$name}', location = '{$location}' WHERE id = '{$edit}'");
     }
```